# DNSBL Server - Linux Distribution Recommendations?

Tags: linux, rbl

I'm preparing to build a publicly accessible DNSBL server.  Which Linux distribution would you recommend for something like this?

I'm mainly interested in:

1. General security
2. Stability
3. Resource utilization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever one you are most familiar with.  If you're coming at this with no prior experience, then whatever the person you're getting your local support from is familiar with.  There is little enough difference between the various Linux distributions (and the BSDs) to make it worth choosing one for any reason other than administrative simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on your habits, you need to use what you are the more confortable with. Well let's say as a mast... monkey [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/).